# Query the Adobe analytics API

Tags: python

has someone ever used python to query Adobe analytics API?
Do you have a template of the code? I cannot find a way to query the API with python using adobe most updated documentation

thanks

Comment: The Adobe API to ***what***? There are probably many of them.

Comment: Sorry #martineau I forgot to specify. To query Adobe analytcs API, in order to retrieve the list of evar, props and events.

Answer (score 1):

I actually developed a python module to use the 1.4 version of the Analytics API. 
You can check it out here : [http://www.datanalyst.info/python/adobe-api/adobe-analytics-api-introduction/](http://www.datanalyst.info/python/adobe-api/adobe-analytics-api-introduction/?camp=sm~stackoverflow~adobe-questions)

It will return you either a dataframe or a csv file.

Let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

You have to use REST 1.4 in order to send the request and get Response in JSON then show the request as per your format.There is no specific format for that as it depends on specific requirement.

Link for [API Explorer](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/api-explorer)

In case you looking for sample Python Library then check 
A [Python Library To Access Omniture's SiteCatalyst](https://github.com/RobGoretsky/omniture_py) Reporting API ,though it 5 years old but to get idea it is not bad.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of raw requests to the REST API you might want to check out the latest version of [this framework](https://github.com/SaturnFromTitan/adobe_analytics) for Python >=3.5